# Lag per "year" in Rstudio

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty coding this mixed model. The model has independent variables: year(character), temperature(numeric), precipitation(numeric), and name(character). Dependent variables: size(numeric) and surviving (numeric). And random effects: weight(numeric), length(numeric), and ID(character).

Per year, I do not have a uniform amount of data, but I'm looking to lag independent variables: year(character), temperature(numeric), precipitation(numeric) (maybe name, too?) by one year. How would I make my code lag according to the year and not just the line?

I tried this code:

```
    data$MeanDailyTemp_lag <- c(NA, head(data$Temperature, -1))
    data$AvgDailyPrecipitation_lag <- c(NA, head(data$Precipitation, -1))
    data$Year_lag <- c(NA, head(data$Year, -1))

    model <- lmer(c(Size, Surviving) ~ Temperature + Temperature_lag + Precipitation +    
Precipitation_lag + Name + Year + Year_lag + (1|Weight) + (1|Length) + (1|ID), data = data)
```

But it looks like it's only lagging 1 line and not a whole year. This error comes up:

```
>Error in model.frame.default(data = data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE, formula = c(Size,  :
    variable lengths differ (found for 'Temperature')
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you created your `data` frame by first creating a handful of vector objects and then assembling them with `data.frame(..)`, meaning you now have both `data$Temperature` and `Temperature`. From there, perhaps you did some updates to data that somehow removed that column and/or changed the number of rows. Am I close? It would be much easier to help if we had a reproducible question including sample data (`dput(x)`), please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for many more details on that. Thanks!